# How to add test cases /requirements suites from other test plans to new test plan and delete them without deleting the original

Tags: testing, tfs, testcase, microsoft-test-manager, test-suite

I am trying to decide on the structure my test cases/suites should have in TFS 2018 (and MTM).

I want to divide based on sprints eg Sprint 1 one test plan, Sprint 2 another test plan etc.
These plans might have the same test cases/ suites.

The available options I found in order to achieve this is to:

1. Clone the test plan A and create a test plan B by selecting which test suites i want to bring to the new plan.
2. Create test suites by referencing
3. Add existing test cases to test plan

The first way is good because the new plans are separate from the old ones so if i delete or make changes to the new test cases it won't update or delete the original ones in the previous sprint. The problem with this way though, is that if i want to add in a later phase some tests from a previous sprint there is no way to clone it in that specific new sprint (it always create a new one as far as I know)

The other two ways are good because you can add anytime new test cases or test suites from the previous to the new sprint but in case you want to delete a test case /suite from the new test plan, it will delete this test suite/case from the previous test plan as well. And i would like to avoid that so that i know what exactly i have run in previous sprints.

A fourth way which i don't think it is a good way, it is to just have a single test plan with different folders for each sprint and just copy test cases between the folders.

What is the best way to achieve what I want ?

Answer (score 1):

There will be only one test plan. And it will have test suites and all your test cases under them.
  Test Suite1 (12 test cases)
    Ready (5)
    NotReady (7)

Every time, you just move the test cases between these Ready, NotReady folders. And every time you will execute only test cases in "Ready" folder.

In sprint 1, if you want to execute test cases 1,2,5,6 only. Then move only 1,2,5,6 test cases to "ready" folder and the rest in to "NotReady" folder.